# Bash check reg expresion one or more times

Tags: bash, shell-script, regular-expression

I want to check if the variable 'X' is in the following parttern `[a-zA-Z0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+`, I check it with `if [[ "${X}" =~ [a-zA-Z0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+ ]]`

Now I want to add and option that this pattern can be inserted more then one and in this case it will be seperated by `,`. I guess I can to something like `[a-zA-Z0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+[,[a-zA-Z0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+]*`. My question is if I can do it shorter then that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want `^[a-zA-Z0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+(,[a-zA-Z0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+)*$`, with parenthesis instead of brackets in the `(,...)*` part and with the pattern locked to the start and end of the string (otherwise it's enough for a part of the string to match).

One option is to leave the regex like that, but just store the repeating part in a variable:

```
p='[a-zA-Z0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+'
s='foo:12:34,bar:56:78'
[[ $s =~ ^$p(,$p)*$ ]] && echo yes
```

Or, stick a leading comma in the *value*, and just change the RE to `(,[a-zA-Z0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+)+`:

```
q='^(,[a-zA-Z0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+)+$'
[[ ,$s =~ $q ]] && echo yes
```

---

However, if you're going to process the values in the list within the script, you'll need to split it to parts sooner or later, so you might just split first and test each part separately:

```
s='adsf,bar:56:78'
p='^[a-zA-Z0-9]+:[0-9]+:[0-9]+$'
IFS=, read -a a <<< "$s"
for x in "${a[@]}"; do 
    if [[ $x =~ $p ]]; then 
        echo "$x is ok";
    else 
        echo "$x is not ok"; 
    fi
done
```

Comment: Adding `,` to the begining of the original string simple the issue!